# "Fire and forget" with structured concurrency and coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I have a little endpoint that looks like this

```
val numbers = it.bodyAsString.parseJsonList<Numbers>()
processedNumbers = numberService.process(numbers)
GlobalScope.launch {
    sqsService.sendToSqs(processedNumbers)
}
it.response.setStatusCode(204).end()
```

The reason why I use GlobalScope is because the producer does only need the acknowledge after the numbers have been processed so I am trying to do a fire and forget in a parallel track to be able to immediately respond to the producer

What would be the “best practice” way of doing this with structured currency? Should I create my own scope (like fireAndForgetScope instead of GlobalScope)?

Comment: You seem to contradict yourself: If the producer needs the acknowledgement after processing the numbers, you can't respond immediately!? Can you clarify?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I sure can! What would happen in my above example is that the producer would get the acknowledgement before the messages are sent to SQS but after the numbers have been processed. So the producer should not have to wait for the SQS-send

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already guessed, creating your own scope would be a good solution in this case.
You can define it as member of your controller:

```
private val bgScope = CoroutineScope(newFixedThreadPoolContext(4, "background-tasks"))
```

Then usage is very similar to what you're doing:

```
val numbers = it.bodyAsString.parseJsonList<Numbers>()
processedNumbers = numberService.process(numbers)
bgScope.launch {
    sqsService.sendToSqs(processedNumbers)
}
it.response.setStatusCode(204).end()
```

Comment: Why use four threads for bg jobs, assuming they're non-blocking? One thread would probably be able to handle a million ops per second.

Comment: You can use singleThreadContext, but I usually prefer to be safe than sorry. Coroutine can still starve the thread it runs on, if it's written badly. Having thread pool mitigates that issue.

Comment: That hides bugs, doesn't it? It will cause your app to misbehave less often, and you won't be able to reproduce it. It's against the "fail fast and loud" doctrine.

Comment: Wouldn't like to argue about different doctrines. What I wonder though after looking at my solution some more is whether simply using `Dispatchers.IO` would be more appropriate. Not sure.

Comment: `Dispatchers.IO` is there for blocking network operations. If `sendToSqs` is a blocking operation, then coroutines don't help with anything, we should just fire off a job to an executor service or whatever else we do.

Comment: Note that `bgScope`now has a `Job` which can be cancelled on a child's failure, preventing further background jobs to launch. To avoid that, `SupervisorJob` should be used