# How to: Grpc fire and forget async api call in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, grpc, kotlin-coroutines

I have a gRPC endpoint: A. I would like to async call another Grpc endpoint: B and return response back without having to wait for the response from B.

How would I create a "fire and forget" async coroutine to make the request?

I know that GlobalScope.launch is highly discouraged due to possible memory leaks.
[Why not use GlobalScope.launch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54335365/why-not-use-globalscope-launch)

API call for Endpoint B takes probably less than 2 seconds.

Is GlobalScope.launch the okay way to achieve this or is there a better way?

Comment: `GlobalScope.launch()` is discouraged **specifically** because it is a fire and forget. If you really like such behavior, then you can use it.

Comment: It's _fire and forget_ that is discouraged by Kotlin, really.  But nothing about this is specific to gRPC; if you want to do something fire-and-forget, you do it the same way you do it with any coroutine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Fire and forget" with structured concurrency and coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53619118/fire-and-forget-with-structured-concurrency-and-coroutines)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks for answering the question. I tried the way suggested in the link you shared by using CoroutineScope.launch. It waits for the response to return before return to caller.

Comment: That should only be an issue if you used the wrong `CoroutineScope`.

Comment: BTW, do consider if you should add some back-pressure for the creation of "fire-and-forget" tasks.

Comment: @GeorgeLeung could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Each request towards endpoint A creates a request for endpoint B. If A receives a higher request per second than B is capable of handling, you risk overloading B, and/or having too many in-flight request to B. You have to decide what to do in such a scenario (drop the requests to B? make A wait?). https://netflixtechblog.medium.com/performance-under-load-3e6fa9a60581