# Calling Fire-And-Forget Methods - Which Scope?

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, scope

I'm overriding the `analyze()` method of `ImageAnalysys.Analyzer`, so I want it to execute and return as soon as possible. I've got a method that I want to call from `analyze()`, which will manipulate some member variables and eventually want to notify a `View` that it has something new to show, but it is lengthy. Thus, I'd like to queue that method for execution but return to `analyze()` immediately.

I was using `GlobalScope.launch { fireAndForgetMethod() }` and that (apparently) works as intended, but I get the 'delicate API' warning and the help popup suggests it is not a good idea. I've seen `MainScope().launch {}` and mentions of viewModelScope and lifecycleScope. But then I've seen articles such as [How to: Grpc fire and forget async api call in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77047151/how-to-grpc-fire-and-forget-async-api-call-in-kotlin) which suggest that even just using fire-and-forget is discouraged.

I've recently learned about JavaScript's `async`, `await` and `Promise` architecture so I have a vague idea of what Kotlin's `suspend` might do, but I think I need a more intelligent answer - code may *seem* to work, but be dodgy.

1. If I mark `fireAndForgetMethod()` as `suspend` and make a normal call to that from `analyze()`, will it return immediately from the call and is this the right technique? I don't need an answer from the method.
2. If that's not the way, what scope should I use for `launch {}`?
3. Is there another (approved) way to do lengthy operations without blocking `analyze()`? (The data required for the long method *comes* from `analyze()`, so somehow that's where I need to trigger it). What about a worker thread, and setting a flag in the thread to say 'GO!'?

Comment: The reason GlobalScope is marked as delicate is because doing fire and forget operations in general is delicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You will also have to mark `analyze()` as `suspend` method. A normal call to `fireAndForgetMethod()` will then wait until the method is finished, before continuing.
2. Ideally, you should use `coroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO | DEFAULT | MAIN)` depending on the type of work you do in `fireAndForgetMethod()`. Although, when the scope is finished, it will wait until all its tasks are finished too. i.e., This would first print `"Async"`, before it gets to the `"Test"`:

```
runBlocking { // Only needed if your function is not already marked as `suspend`
    coroutineScope {
        launch {
            delay(5000)
            println("Async")
        }
    }
}
println("Test")
```

3. You can use threads. You can use some background worker if your system/framework (e.g., Android, Spring, etc.) supports that.

If you truly want the function to be executed in the background, without having any scope that could await it, using `GlobalScope` should be fine.

Comment: The inner `coroutineScope` is unnecessary if you’re using an outer `runBlocking`.